# Working with djangorestframework 0.3.0 and django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I upgraded django and all apps I was using to the recent version but because of the huge changes made between djangorestframework 0.4.0 and 3.3.0 I've returned to 0.4.0 and opted to fix the simpler issue it had importing json from `django.utils` and edited it to `import json` now I'm getting an error templatedoesnotexist

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://kbuzz.webfactional.com/rest/movies/?device=browser

Django Version: 1.7.10
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'rest_framework',
 'haystack',
 'lamusoftware.generic',
 'mptt',
 'bootstrapform',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'oauth2client',
 'articles',
 'banners',
 'common',
 'directory',
 'events',
 'galleries',
 'marketplace',
 'movies',
 'pages',
 'profiles',
 'search',
 'stats',
 'minidetector',
 'mobile',
 'reports',
 'favorites',
 'braces',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'wordofmouth',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_mobile',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'markup_deprecated')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.RedirectMovie')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django_mobile.loader.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/kb/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/autocomplete_light/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/rest_framework/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/haystack/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/mptt/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/bootstrapform/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/reports/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/favorites/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/allauth/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/wordofmouth/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/ckeditor/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)
/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/debug_toolbar/templates/djangorestframework/api.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/views.py" in dispatch
  246.         return self.final(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/views.py" in final
  199.         return self.render(response)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/mixins.py" in render
  251.             content = renderer.render(response.cleaned_content, media_type)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/renderers.py" in render
  342.         template = loader.get_template(self.template)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  144.     template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  136.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /rest/movies/
Exception Value: djangorestframework/api.html
```

**UPDATE**

I edited settings file from `rest_framework` to `djangorestframework` now getting this error mimetype must have been removed for httpresponse.

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://kbuzz.webfactional.com/rest/movies/categories/?device=browser

Django Version: 1.7.10
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'djangorestframework',
 'haystack',
 'lamusoftware.generic',
 'mptt',
 'bootstrapform',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'oauth2client',
 'articles',
 'banners',
 'common',
 'directory',
 'events',
 'galleries',
 'marketplace',
 'movies',
 'pages',
 'profiles',
 'search',
 'stats',
 'minidetector',
 'mobile',
 'reports',
 'favorites',
 'braces',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'wordofmouth',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_mobile',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'markup_deprecated')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.RedirectMovie')


Traceback:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/views.py" in dispatch
  246.         return self.final(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/views.py" in final
  199.         return self.render(response)
File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/djangorestframework/mixins.py" in render
  256.         resp = HttpResponse(content, mimetype=response.media_type, status=response.status)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  318.         super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /rest/movies/categories/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have switched back to rest framwork 0.4.0, you should change the value in your `INSTALLED_APPS` from `rest_framework` back to `djangorestframework`.

Then the app template loader should find the template in the `djangorestframework/templates` directory.

Comment: Thanks that  removed that error now I'm getting different one please look at my update

Comment: mimetype in this line is bringing the error resp = HttpResponse(content, mimetype=response.media_type, status=response.status)

Comment: It should be `content_type`, not `mimetype` in Django 1.5+. Django rest framework 0.4.0 was released in 2012. I don't think that it's a good idea to try to use it with Django 1.7, which was released two years later. I can't help you fix all the errors you get when trying to make it work.

Comment: I got it working I know this isn't the easiest way but it will do for now. The data goes to an app and needs to be working, and the site was designed by the senior developer where I used to work so rewriting will take time I can have now with the staging server.